# Any experience with the "Extremely limited pedestal reservations" for statue of liberty at the ticket office?

Tags: sightseeing, new-york-city, landmarks

I am planning a trip to New York (family of 4 adults + 1 baby) and obviously would like to visit the Statue of Liberty. I did not get the tickets in advance, and with two weeks remaining for the trip, the website does not have any tickets available.

However the [website](http://www.nps.gov/stli/planyourvisit/visiting-the-pedestal.htm) states

> Extremely limited pedestal reservations may be available at the ticket
>   offices early in the morning. Pedestal reservations are not available
>   on Liberty Island.

Does anyone have experience getting them? How early in the morning is early enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention the NPS website. [Also on that same page, it states](http://www.nps.gov/stli/planyourvisit/visiting-the-pedestal.htm):

> Due to its popularity, access to the pedestal is limited and requires
>   reservations. Statue Cruises is the official source for pedestal
>   reservations as well as the company that provides ferry transportation
>   to the island. Advanced reservations may be made online or by
>   telephone.

So that may be a far easier way of ensuring you get them.

How early is early enough in the morning is going to depend on the season, weather, events and luck.  However, the first ferry with the official Statue Cruises [is 9.30 in the morning](http://www.statuecruises.com/schedule.aspx) from Battery Park, so make sure you're there before then.  One would figure it'd be easy to pass there earlier in the morning, see if there's a queue, join it if there is, or go get a coffee and come back, if you're really certain about getting there early.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Agree that reservations in advance is the best option. I was looking for alternatives provided if one did not have advance reservations (and reservations to the crown get filled up weeks if not months in advance).